# Rails image tag not accepting class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in in my view

```
<%= image_tag("Logo.png"), :class => "logo" %>
```

How is this not working? I keep getting a syntax error saying its expecting a `)` not a `,`

Thanks

Comment: Correct bracketing is important, `class: "logo" is a second argument to `image_link` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the code here:

```
<%= image_tag("logo.png", :class => "logo") %>
```